# How to realize the feature by one SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get the result:

```
name monthly_count total_count
a    10            20
b    15            25
```

About monthly_count:

```
select name, count(*) as monthly_count from table_name where updated_at = yyyymm
```

About total_count:

```
select count(*) as total_count from table_name
```

I want to find a way to realize it by one SQL,but I don't know how to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one common approach:

```
SELECT t.name
     , COUNT(IF(t.updated_at = yyyymm, 1, NULL)) AS monthly_count
     , COUNT(1) AS total_count 
  FROM table_name t 
 GROUP
    BY t.name
```

The trick to getting the monthly_count is to use an expression that returns a non-null value when a condition is true, and return a NULL when it's not.

An equivalent result can be returned using the SUM function, in place of the COUNT:

```
SELECT t.name
     , SUM(t.updated_at = yyyymm) AS monthly_count
     , SUM(1) AS total_count 
  FROM table_name t 
 GROUP
    BY t.name
```

**FOLLOWUP**

You can use any expression that returns a 1 or 0. To check multiple conditions, you can use the `AND`  and/or `OR` operators

e.g.

```
SELECT t.name
     , SUM(t.updated_at = yyyymm AND t.flag='TRUE') AS monthly_true_count
     , SUM(t.flag='TRUE') AS total_true_count 
  FROM table_name t
 GROUP
    BY t.name
```

This is shorthand for the equivalent:

```
SELECT t.name
     , SUM(IF( t.updated_at = yyyymm AND t.flag='TRUE', 1,0)) AS monthly_true_count
     , SUM(IF(t.flag='TRUE',1,0)) AS total_true_count 
  FROM table_name t
 GROUP
    BY t.name
```

Comment: Thank you very much!It's clearly!Another question:If I add a condition to the monthly and total search,is that looks like:`SUM(IF(t.updated_at = yyyymm ADN t.flag = true)) | SUM(t.flag = true)`?

Comment: I had an error in the query. The IF() function takes three parameters.  A boolean expression will return a value of 1, 0 or NULL, so we can wrap a boolean expression in a SUM() function. Answer has been edited, hopefully answering your question.